# how to remove gridview's blue color when items are pressed

Tags: android, gridview

When `gridview`'s items are Pressed there is Blue color.
How can I remove that color?

I tried my best to ask clearly...

Comment: I think you should show a screenshot, and point what is wrong there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you have:

From code:

```
gridView.setSelector(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

From xml:

```
android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
```